# Connecting RStudio with Remote R machine

Tags: r, hadoop, rstudio, rhadoop

I have RStudio installed on my Windows machine and R installed on one of the nodes of a hadoop cluster. I want to connect RStudio to that slave machine and want to run my R script. I have all the R packages required for hadoop integration installed on that slave machine. I can not use Windows-based R.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RStudio to connect to remote Hadoop server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828643/rstudio-to-connect-to-remote-hadoop-server)

Comment: @Christopher : I read about mentioned link, it says that you need to install packages in RStudio but in this way i will not be able to access my actual cluster.Even i am not sure if i run any map reduce job then how it will behave  in windows..

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: Sure  Christopher. I wanted to write some map reduce job using R. So i was planning to use RStudio so that it can be further used for visualization as well. I have data placed in hadoop cluster and R installed in one of the data node. So i wanted to connect my data node where i am having R installed and would like my R scrip to be executed on that machine. Output generated from my job then can be further send to visualization.
Let me know if it is not clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to [install RStudio Server](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server) on that machine (Linux) and then access RStudio Server by pointing your web browser to `<IP ADDRESS>:8787`.

Comment: This isn't really a solution as it requires using a web browser rather than the RStudio IDE.